# How to create database driven permalinks in Zend Framework?

Tags: php, zend-framework, doctrine

I want to know the method/approach should i have to follow in ZF. Please keep in mind that User can design the permalinks of his own choice.

Comment: http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.router.html#zend.controller.router.routes

Comment: Rewrite Router comes with six basic types of routes. which one should i follow ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Steps to create database driven permalinks in Zend Framework:

1. this can be managed by database and user friendly.

   1. Please create a table for permalinks (field permalink, exactlink).
   2. when user hint a url(permalink ) then you can get the exactlink from database according to permalink.
   3. then redirect the page on exact link by zend routing

Please go to this link and read the zend routing

http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.router.html#zend.controller.router.routes

Answer (score 1):

Here is a great tutorial to setup routing in zend framework in the case of permalinks (vanity urls).

This tutorial describes how to categorize the routes and how to check in databse to find the **exact link** for a vanity url (permalink).

http://tfountain.co.uk/blog/2010/9/9/vanity-urls-zend-framework